# Identify a column where data has been entered multi line

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise 11.2.0.4.0, PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0

I have a Table, which contains an address column (NVARCHAR2(50)). This column is supposed to be line 1 of the address only.

There are a small few records where the address was entered incorrectly into the column, this is supposed to be the first line of the address but it seems through the application a user can enter the first line of the address multiple times, or even the full address in the first line of this address column.

[image: Screenshot1]

Expanding record1 (Double clicking the column in Toad) will show this. Note the extra lines.

[image: screenshot 2]

I need to write SQL which will identify columns that contain the first line of the address entered in this incorrect format (e.g. multiple lines or tabbed etc.)
I found this on another stack exchange post but it doesn’t help with my multiple line situation.

select * from tablename where regexp_like (columnname, chr(9));

I wrote this SQL to repro  and it seems to demo my scenario.

```
CREATE TABLE XRAY_TEST (ADD_LI1 NVARCHAR2(50));

INSERT INTO XRAY_TEST (ADD_LI1)
VALUES ('25 CAMBRIDGE STREET
25 CAMBRIDGE STREET
25 CA');
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO XRAY_TEST (ADD_LI1)
VALUES ('25 WESTWIND CRESCENT');
COMMIT;

SELECT *
FROM XRAY_TEST
```

So to summarize I want to be able to identify any record in the table that has been entered like record1 (e.g. multiline).

Comment: Try using chr(10) or char(13) instead of chr(9) and see what you get

Comment: `chr(9)` is a tab character. You want `chr(10)` (linefeed). I would expect that to be a safer bet than `chr(13)` (carriage return) which is Windows-specific and not necessarily used by application form fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for values  that contain linefeeds, so:

```
where somecol like '%'||chr(10)||'%'
```

Or alternatively,

```
where instr(somecol, chr(10)) > 0
```

A regex here would be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

try matching for regular expression for new line, this query should result only those records where you have address spread across more than 1 lines

```
SELECT * 
FROM XRAY_TEST 
where ADD_LI1 regexp '(\n)';
```